# $dE$ stands in my way to know the density of states in bulk crystal, how to get rid of it?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, integration, mathematics, calculus, density-of-states

In a book about semiconductors, I found the following formula for the density of states:

$$D(E)dE=\frac{(2m)^{3/2}E^{1/2}}{2\pi^2\hbar^2}dE. \tag{1}$$

In that book, the important lesson from this formula is that density of states grows like a square root of energy, and increases with the mass of a particle in question (electron or hole).

But I'm confused by the presence of the $dE$, because I have no idea how to do calculations with it (except for taking an integral from $E_1$ to $E_2$). Let's say I want to know what is the density of states at particular energy $E_1$.

Assuming I know the mass of particle... still after calculations all i get is:
$D(E_1)\; dE=constant\; dE$

How do I get rid of $dE$ to calculate the $D(E_1)$? I know that they don't just "cancel-out". My final goal is to make a plot of density of states as a function of energy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they just "cancel-out".

The density of states in you case is:

$$ D(E) \propto \sqrt{E}.$$

The reason they put the differentials $\mathrm{d}E$ next to it is because usually you don't care about $D(E)$ per se. You want, say, the total number of states up to energy $E$:
$$ N(E) = \int_0^E D(E') \, \mathrm{d}E'.$$

When you plot them, this is what they look like (in arbitrary units):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the differentials always cancel-out, if on the opposite sides of the equation?

Comment: I guess mathematically you’d have to change them from an infinitesimal quantity $dE$ to a finite small element $\delta E$ first. But yeah essentially. You can also just say that $dE$ is the same on both sides of the equation, so to have the equality you need the “other bit” to match.